# Trouble adding cells to a tableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

I have a page with a button on it. When the button is pressed, i want the table view on the next page to add a cell with a label that has the text of `1` and i want there to be a picture also, but i know how to do this. I just want to add a cell to a table view when a button is pressed on the page before the table. How can i do this? Ive tried this code:

```
FinalCartViewController * viewController = (FinalCartViewController    
*)self.parentViewController;
custom.customCellLabel.text = @"1";
[viewController addObject:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject:   
custom.customCellLabel.text forKey:@"name"]];
```

`custom` is an ivar that is created from the `FinalCartViewController`.

This code was in the method for the button that i want to use to add the cell. And i used `[myTalbleView reloadData];` in the tableView's `viewDidLoad`. But my app crashes when i press the button to add the cell. Could somebody please help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
FinalCartViewController * viewController = (FinalCartViewController    
*)self.parentViewController;
```

If the FinalCartViewController (I assume is the Table View) is the NEXT page, how can it be the PARENT view? The Parent view refers to the previous view.

You need to initialise the FinalCartViewController and save reference to it, so you can add objects to it. Although, the better practice would be to have a shared datasource that you add to and then pass to the FinalCartViewController.

Comment: hey man thanks for the reply! :D but, im a noob and not very good at code yet, so could you please explain to me a little bit better how to do this by sharing the datasource? Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Really hard to explain unfortunately... it would require writing a whole tutorial, of which there are many :) The gist of it is you have a data storage, say a NSMutableArray. When you want to update the table, you add the data to the Array, NOT to the tableview. Then you pass the array to the tableView and tell it to update when it needs to. This reduces the amount of dependency between the two views, and the tableView will simply just read what is in the data provided instead.